# Counting calories and following the limit

Tags: diet, calories

I want to ask how do you count the calories for example of something with undefined calories like a soup or some new sort of home made sandwiches. Also I would like to know how can I calculate my calories limit ( 91kg, 176cm ).

Comment: You can also use apps like My fitness Pal and others, that have a lot of foods and the corresponding calories. Of course it's an estimation.

Comment: What do you need your calories limit for? If it's for weight loss purposes, you might not be on the right track. See this question: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily

Comment: related [Is 3400 calories a day unreasonable for me?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/is-3400-calories-a-day-unreasonable-for-me?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Estimated calories you burn throughout day](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/942/estimated-calories-you-burn-throughout-day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calories are not available from a label, you have to do the next best thing.  Break down what's in the food and consult a nutrition guide.  For example, for soup, if you knew the amount of chicken, veggies, etc. you can come up with a **rough estimate** of the caloric count.  In order to estimate, you'll need to become proficient on serving sizes.  Most nutrition guides will define calorie counts in terms of common serving sizes.  As for calorie limits, that would depend upon what your goals are.  For example, losing, gaining, or, maintaining weight.  Again, the "limit" would be an estimation and not a hard number.  It would need to be adjusted based on your activity level.