# Energy expenditure (calories burned) equation for running

Tags: running, calories, calculation, vo2max, met

There are numerous online calorie calculators for running (e.g. from [runners world](http://www.runnersworld.com/tools/calories-burned-calculator)).  **What is the underlying formula for calculating energy expenditure while running?**  [This post](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/942/estimated-calories-you-burn-throughout-day) has an excellent answer for the analog of calories burned throughout the day.

Comment: related: [Metabolic Equations for Anaroebic Exercise?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/metabolic-equations-for-anaroebic-exercise)

Comment: related: [Approx. how many calories can I figure I burn per mile?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18688/approx-how-many-calories-can-i-figure-i-burn-per-mile)

Comment: related: [Does burning calories by running depend only on distance, and not speed?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/does-burning-calories-by-running-depend-only-on-distance-and-not-speed?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Is it possible to measure calorie burn from heart rate alone?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worth noting, without data from an ECG (heart rate monitor) and face mask based gas analyzers, along with details of the gradient, wind speed, and surface there aren't any **accurate** equations.

The best you can do is to estimate a [VO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max) (mL·kg-1·min-1) figure, and convert that into a Kcal one:

> **Kcal/Min ~= respiratoryExchangeRatio * massKg * VO2 / 1000**

**Note:** respiratoryExchangeRatio is **5.0** for blood sugars, but drops to **4.86** for freeing energy from fat, so if the run is of more than a few min's use this.

Personally I prefer the [ACMS Running VO2max](http://blue.utb.edu/mbailey/handouts/pdf/MetCalnew.pdf) equation, as it's relatively simple, will give a number that's accurate within: +/-14.5%, though the conversion to Kcal will multiply the error by a bit, and it's recommended in the paper: *Energy Expenditure of Walking and Running: Comparison with Prediction Equations, Hall et Al, 2003*

> For running, the Léger equation and ACSM prediction model appear to be
>   the most suitable for the prediction of running energy expenditure.

So we have:

> **VO2 = (0.2 * metersMin) + (0.9 * metersMin * fractionalgrade) + 3.5**
>
> on the flat, this equates to:
>
> **VO2 = (0.2 * metersMin) + 3.5**

The Léger equations is simpler, but does not account for gradient:

> **V̇O2 = 2.209 + 3.1633 * kph**

Though a not dissimilar degree of accuracy is claimed by the [MET](https://sites.google.com/site/compendiumofphysicalactivities/Activity-Categories) tables and formula, and is even simpler:

> **Kcal ~= METS * bodyMassKg * timePerformingHours**

Where MET is short for Metabolic Equivalent of Task, and is just an abstract way to quantify the relative energy cost of an activity, a number of sites offer MET estimates for specific activities eg.

- [Compendium of Physical Activities](https://sites.google.com/site/compendiumofphysicalactivities/Activity-Categories)
- [procon.org - MET Values for 800+ Activities](http://golf.procon.org/view.resource.php?resourceID=004786)
- [Metabolic Equivalents (METS) in Exercise Testing, Exercise
  Prescription, and Evaluation of Functional Capacity](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/clc.4960130809/asset/4960130809_ftp.pdf?v=1&t=ic8uvfk6&s=c0458f8a0e42ff2c0fc9557625b42e029b78e69f)

Comment: How does the incline in degrees convert to the "fractionalgrade" ?

Answer (score 4):

I googled a bit and stumbled upon the following formula. [The source](http://fitnowtraining.com/2012/01/formula-for-calories-burned/) claims it's from Journal of Sports Sciences.

> Men use the following formula:
>
> Calories Burned = [(Age x 0.2017) + (Weight x 0.09036) + (Heart Rate x
>   0.6309) -- 55.0969] x Time / 4.184.
>
> Women use the following formula:
>
> Calories Burned = [(Age x 0.074) -- (Weight x 0.05741) + (Heart Rate x
>   0.4472) -- 20.4022] x Time / 4.184.
>
> Calculation
>
> For example, here’s my formula  based on a 49 year old male weighing
>   155 for a workout where my heart rate averages about 148 bpm
>   throughout a 60-minute FitCamp workout.
>
> [(49 x 0.2017) + (155 x 0.09036) + (148 x 0.6309) – 55.0969] x
>   60/4.184 =
>
> [9.8833 + 14.0058 + 93.3792 – 55.0969] x 14.3403 = 891.47 calories (or
>   15 kcal/min)

This is the most comprehensive (and quite recent) formula I could find, which takes in account many factors that others don't (age, heart rate etc.). Hope it helps :)

Comment: This looks great!  Thanks.  I just don't get why there aren't more comparable things for running explicitly.

Comment: I'd double check the formula above, as a quick Google shows the supposed male formula being used in an all female study: [COMPARISION OF ENERGY EXPENDITURE DURING WALKING AND
RUNNING ON TRACK BEFORE AND AFTER TRAINING IN YOUNG
HEALTHY ADULT WOMEN](http://www.ijmhr.org/ijpr_articles_vol1_4/329.pdf), Note: both the site and the paper are vague as to the origin of the formula.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty late to the party on this one but thought it was worth adding that the [JavaScript behind the runners world calculator](https://www.runnersworld.com/sites/runnersworld.com/files/custom-js/1263036-f1703073e5ee4e4ce5923dc03ff02975.js) is pretty simple. Looking at the function toolSubmit (which is called when the "Calculate" button is clicked) it's clear that it calculates calories burned as:

```
calories burned = distance run (kilometres) x weight of runner (kilograms) x 1.036
```

This is rounded to a whole number and then formatted as the message displayed in the browser.

Comment: Ha, interesting.  Presumably the constant (`1.036`) is based on something like the MET tables mentioned in https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/25564/7397

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix perhaps it's using the MET tables, but I'd bet a 3.6% discriminant is an act of laziness more than anything else. It's likely the programmer was given a set of distances, weights and calories and they just changed this constant by +/- 0.1% until it fit reasonably well. These kind of sets are what drives a lot of calorie logic on treadmills. It's worth taking away from this that a lot of these calculators are really poorly written. This one was just easy to see how poorly written it is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, there are quite a few different formulas available, depending on who was doing the research, and when it was performed. To some extent, the method used to determine the calories burned can have an effect on the formula.

http://www.stanford.edu/~clint/Run_Walk2004a.rtf

That is a link to a published study from Syracuse University, comparing several different methods of calculating calorie burn. If you are looking at a watch, treadmill or other device that is measuring it for you, somewhere in their literature they should be describing what method they are using.