# Derive the MET equation for caloric expenditure estimate

Tags: calories, energy, metabolism, met

A [Metabolic Equivalent of Task (METs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent_of_task) is:

```
1 MET := Consumption of 3.5 mL_O2/kg/min ~= 1 kcal/kg/hr
```

Most online calculators that use MET to estimate caloric burn use:

```
Eq. 1) Cal_kcal = Duration_min * (Mets_MET * 3.5 * Mass_kg / 200)
```

But **none** of them derive it or provide a proof to get from `3.5 mL_O2/kg/min => 1 kcal/kg/hr`! Where did "200" come from? Intuitively, knowing the units of MET `kcal/kg/hr`, you'd likely simply perform this following conversion instead:

```
Eq. 2) Cal_kcal = Duration_hr * Mets_MET * Mass_kg
```

But this differs by 5% from `Eq. 1`. **Please derive `Eq. 1` and explain all units/constants** so that we may understand why it is used in almost all MET calculator (and not Eq. 2).

- https://www.healthline.com/health/what-are-mets#calorie-connection
- https://howdyhealth.tamu.edu/use-metabolic-equivalents-mets-to-calculate-calories-burned/
- https://captaincalculator.com/health/calorie/calories-burned-running-calculator/
- https://www.cmsfitnesscourses.co.uk/blog/using-mets-to-calculate-calories-burned/
- https://www.omnicalculator.com/sports/calories-burned
- https://blog.nasm.org/metabolic-equivalents-for-weight-loss
- https://www.acefitness.org/resources/pros/expert-articles/6434/5-things-to-know-about-metabolic-equivalents/
- https://www.gymondo.com/magazin/en/workout/what-are-mets-and-how-to-calculate-them-to-burn-more-calories
- https://www.convertcalculator.com/templates/met-calculator/

##### Hint

These links are the closest I've ever seen to a derivation: [Metabolic Equations for Anaerobic Exercise?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/metabolic-equations-for-anaerobic-exercise) and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/25564/40079. However, there is no source, explanation of why 5/1000 is used (vs 4.X), or what the units all are. Even more confusing, they both conclude by using `Eq. 2` not `Ex. 1` like all online calculators!

Answer (score 0):

You won't get to eqn 1 starting from your definition of MET.

MET is VO2 in milliliters per minute per kilogram body mass divided by 3.5. So using the conventional value of: 1 liter of O2 consumed is roughly equivalent to burning 5 kcal we get:

a) E = MET * 3.5 / 1000 ml/l * 5 kcal * duration_min * mass_kg

which is

b) E = MET * 3.5 / 200 ml/l*kcal * duration_min * mass_kg

which is eqn 1 in your question. That is why you get a deviation of 5% since its not 1 kcal/kg/h per MET as given by your definition but 1.05 kcal/kg/h per MET.